# Run g++ as user instead of root on OS X (xcode)

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, macos, g++

On Mac OS X 10.9.2 I tried g++ at the unix command line and it required me to download xcode. I did that successfully. I again tried g++ at the unix command line and it wanted me to be root instead: "Agreeing ti the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo." But, I don't know the root password - it never came up in the set up (I purchased the macbook pro new today). How can I get g++ to run from the command line as a regular user (not root)?

Comment: Use `sudo g++` to run it as root using your own password. It's only a one-time thing, you will be able to run it normally after that. You can also open Xcode to agree through the GUI then run g++ normally.

Comment: Exactly as you said. Solved my problem. Thanks ejno and ughoavgfhw!!

Comment: If your question has been answered please close it (or write your own answer and accept it)